# Which unlocked Android 2.2 phones are close to or better than the N1 for development?

Tags: android

I hope this isn't too off topic for this forum, but I have been developing Android apps using an unlocked N1 with 2.2 and would like to continue with two additional unlocked Android phones. [A similar question was asked in January](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133296/best-phone-for-doing-android-sw-development), but much has changed since then, eg: Brightstar is out of N1 stock and there are a lot of new devices on the market. Also, I plan to target 2.2 and up since apps are not MicroSD loadable (as far as I know) on earlier OS versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always better to have combination of **devices in different screen densities like QVGA,HVGA and WVGA**.

You can try also with one more device which has WVGA 480*854 in screen resolution(though it doesn't make a big difference with N1)

Moreover i would **not recommend you to go with 2.2 SDK alone** since the **usage statistics provided by google is just 4.5%** for 2.2 SDK.

http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

A few more 2.2 SDK devices that you can go for

```
1.Motorola Droid
2.HTC EVO 
3.MyTouch 3G
4.HTC Desire
```

Answer (score 1):

My personal favourite was HTC Magic(1.6).......I'm currently working on Motorola Droid....its awesome...I've heard HTC Desire with FROYO is cool...